# how to manipulate the html 5 video progress bar?

Tags: html5-video

Due to the video host rules, I have to split a video(v0) into several small ones(v1,v2,v3), then I have a problem?

How to make the progress bar duration include the sum of each small videos(v1.times+v2.times+v3.times)?

Is there any api available? or should I use javascript to write some code to archive this functionality?

Comment: As Jackson says, your only possibility is to create your own player controls from scratch. Personally I wouldn't bother just to get around a dodgy host, I'd get a new host...